# In C++, is each "statement" also an expression?

Tags: c++, expression, language-lawyer, difference

Could I say that in C++, each statement(without the semicolon) is also an expression?

Also, all expressions, add a semicolon, can become a statement?
Thanks.

Comment: You may find [**this** interesting](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements).

Comment: @BatCoder: _statement_ and _expression_ are well-defined terms in C and C++ (and many other) languages.

Comment: @Mat, yes, but I didn't understand the premise of the question - the ambiguity that the OP faced.  Hence requested the OP to provide some examples.

Comment: @BatCoder Examples are not required, as the terms are well-defined in the C++ standard. It is not up to the OP or anyone else to educate you.

Comment: @BatCoder: Humbly, the premise is quite clear to anyone versed in the structure of the C++ language. You don't need to answer if you're not one of those people. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, a C++ statement is not always an expression. For example a `for` loop is not an expression (of type `void`). So even with using the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) the following is wrong:

```
 /// wrong code, syntactically incorrect in C++
 for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {std::cout<<i<<std::endl;}
 , // this is a comma operator
 x+3
```

<sup>(and you could replace the comma operator by any other operator like `+`, it is still wrong)</sup>

But of course expressions (including assignments and calls) can be used as statements.

Notice that [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) provides, as a *language extension*, [statement exprs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) (and this extension is accepted by [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)); here is a trivial example (the value of the statement expression is given by `2*x`):

```
#include <iostream>

void f (int x) {
   // notice the statement-expr starting inside ({ ... })
   // the last expression inside the braces gives the value
   int y = ({std::cout << "x=" << x << std::endl; 2*x;})+1;
   std::cout << "y=" << y << std::endl;
}
```

With C++11 compilers not accepting that extension, you might create a closure with a [lambda-expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and apply it immediately to get an equivalent effect:

```
void f (int x) {
  int y = ([=](){std::cout << "x=" << x << std::endl; return 2*x;})() + 1;
  std::cout << "y=" << y << std::endl;
}
```

Hopefully an optimizing compiler won't bother creating the intermediate closure and produce code equivalent to what GCC could give (with `g++ -O2`) with the statement expr variant

Some languages, notably Ocaml, Scheme, Haskell, don't have statements or instructions. They have only expressions (and some of them might have some side-effect).

Answer (score 7):

An *expression* followed by a semicolon is indeed an *expression_statement* which is a type of statement.

But the converse is not necessarily true: for example consider the *jump_statement*:

`goto foo;`

here `goto foo` is *not* an expression.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Statements can be composed of any number of things (including expressions), but statements themselves are not expressions.

Have a look at §A.5.